# How to aboid NullPointerException with DatePickerCells?

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I'm working with the GWT DataGrid. I'm using the DatePickerCell:

```
DateTimeFormat dateFormat = DateTimeFormat
            .getFormat(PredefinedFormat.DATE_MEDIUM);
    Column<TriathlonDTO, Date> dateColumn = new Column<ClassDTO, Date>(
            new DatePickerCell(dateFormat)) {
        @Override
        public Date getValue(TriathlonDTO object) {
            return object.getDate();
        }
    };
```

Sometimes I have cells where the Date is null.
If my date is null, the DataGrid shows an empty field what is fine.

But: When I click on the field, the DatePicker window doesn't show up, since the DatePicker class uses the getValue()-Function above, which returns null -> NullPointerException

I don't want to change the getValue() function to return new Date().

Do you have a smart solution to avoid the NPE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, and for now there's no other way than *forking* the code (i;e. make you own copy of `DatePickerCell` that fixes the issue).

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5791#c4 which provides some code.